# How to upgrade Mozc in my Ubuntu 21.04 to the latest build from Github?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, compiling, git, mozc

I just bumped into [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mozc/+bug/1931554) myself. tl;dr good news: it's already fixed few months ago in official git source codes. Bad news: latest version of Mozc available for Ubuntu 21.04 in it's repositories is `2.26.4220.100+dfsg-4ubuntu3` with the version that contain the fix is [2.26.4472.100](https://github.com/google/mozc/issues/510), so straight `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` does not help.

I'm trying to dig into [official docs](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/docs/build_mozc_in_docker.md) for building Mozc in Docker environment, but my knowledge of Ubuntu is lacking to replace present Mozc system with the new one, and I can't find proper guidelines for it in official docs, neither in other answers that mostly address Mozc installation for older versions of Ubuntu from official apt repository.

I would appreciate a lot if anybody could give a bit more detailed steps for building and replacement this system from github sources, without waiting for official repository.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into this problem myself right now

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't find a way to package the newest mozc version, I did find that Anthy works just fine with Anki, and is almost functionally identical to mozc. Just:

`sudo apt-get install ibus-anthy`

Then in settings, add Japanese > Japanese (Anthy) as an input method.

Answer (score 1):

Morning from Lijiang!

I just upgraded my OS from 20.04 to 22.04 yesterday morning, and I bumped into the same problem. (The upgrade itself was due to my failed attempt to use NVDEC-based hardware-decoding for Firefox/FFMPEG, but this was another story.)

I tried the anthy solution from the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1366903/108910).  But ibus-anthy is not very intelligient compared to ibus-mozc.  For example, it is not very convenient to input 頭高型 (あたまだかがた) or 菅義偉 (すがよしひで), and the companion kasumi dictionary editor for anthy never works for me on my system.

Lucikly, I finally made it and upgrade mozc to a version that works with Anki on my fresh 22.04 last night.  Here was how I did it, but remember, YMMV!

I first thought it was an Anki issue (since only Anki observed this problem and other apps just worked fined) and upgrade Anki to the latest version (2.1.65 Qt6) from the official [website](https://docs.ankiweb.net/platform/linux/installing.html).  But to no avail, this does not solve my mozc problem.

However, I also found out from this issue [comment](https://github.com/google/mozc/issues/510#issuecomment-873415793) that the problem was already solved by a newer version of mozc.  Then I tried to upgrade mozc to a newer version.  I used the deb approach, since I don't want to compile everything from source. (I am an ex-programmer now.)  I used this Deiban [webpage](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mozc/) to download the necessary deb files.  I downloaded ibus-mozc ([2.28.4715.102](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mozc/ibus-mozc_2.28.4715.102+dfsg-2.2_amd64.deb)) and related dependencies.  Fortunately, the dependency chain wasn't that deep.  The order I did it was libprotobuf32 ([3.21.12-3](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/protobuf/libprotobuf32_3.21.12-3_amd64.deb)), libabsl20220623 ([20220623.1-1](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/abseil/libabsl20220623_20220623.1-1_amd64.deb)), mozc-server ([2.28.4715.102](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mozc/mozc-server_2.28.4715.102+dfsg-2.2_amd64.deb)), and finally the ibus-mozc proper.

I haven't tried this version of mozc with the Anki ([2.1.15](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/anki) for jammy) from the official Ubuntu repository though.  I guess that it should also work with that too.