# How to downgrade package to the version form previous release of Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, downgrade, mozc

I've stuck with a specific [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364631/how-to-upgrade-mozc-in-my-ubuntu-21-04-to-the-latest-build-from-github) in Mozc package on the latest Ubuntu 21.04, that is of `2.26.4220.100` version. So I figured out I can solve it by downgrading Mozc package to the `2.23.2815.102` version that was working great on 20.04LTS Ubuntu.
Still, when I try to get list of available versions
[image]

it shows the only `2.26.4220.100` version available.

But if we look at the [complete list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ibus-mozc&searchon=names), we can see there are lots of older versions available from previous versions of Ubuntu:
[image]

So for some reason my `apt` just doesn't see repositories for other Ubuntu releases. And my question is how to make it do so, so I could just `sudo apt install «pkg»=«version»`?

Comment: for some reason my apt just doesn't see repositories for other Ubuntu releases That is correct it shows the version that is for the version of Ubuntu you are using. Nothing wrong with apt.

Comment: @David thank you for your answer! So, how to make it do so if I need it?

Comment: If you check the list of dependencies, you will see that issues following a downgrade are likely.

Comment: @pLumo thank you for your advice! Still, I'd like to give it a try, with upgrade it back being always an option. So, how to downgrade it to the version from 20.04 repository?

Comment: I would download manually the old version of the package, install it using `dpkg`, and then pin the version in Synaptic to prevent upgrades.

Comment: @raj thank you for your advice! Yes, I was considering this way as well. Still, at the 'Download' section of https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/source/focal/mozc I can see only .tag.xz archives and not proper .deb packages. Is it possible to install them some way, or am I just looking in the wrong place?

Comment: You are looking in **source** repository - you won't find installable binary packages there. Try here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/focal/allpackages - search (Ctrl+F) for "mozc". It is possible that you will have to downgrade more than one package.

Comment: @raj ouch, you're right. I'm still new to the packages site. Thank you for advising! Yup, that did the trick, I very properly managed to downgrade target packages and everything works great now. Thank you! Regarding prevention from automatic upgrade, I'm using apt instead of Synaptic, so I guess I should just `sudo apt-mark hold` all the packages that I downgraded, right?

Comment: From the description it looks that it should do the same, however I never used this, I always did it via Synaptic. When I run `sudo apt-mark showhold` it doesn't show me the package that I have pinned in Synaptic, so probably the mechanism is different, but the result may be the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method would be probably to manually download the `.deb` file using the "focal" link shown on your screenshot, then install it using `sudo dpkg -i ibus-mozc_2.23.2815.102+dfsg-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb` (because of dependencies, you will probably also need to downgrade `mozc-server` and `mozc-utils-gui` - if installed), and then prevent the packages from further upgrades using either `sudo apt-mark hold ibus-mozc` (and the same for other downgraded packages), or "Lock version" option in Synaptic Package Manager.